# Remote desktop stuck at blank lock screen

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-11

Video and photo of the issue: https://imgur.com/a/DC1ZYhc

I have remote desktop enabled on my desktop PC so I can connect from my laptop when I'm not home (I use a Cloudflare tunnel to connect back to my home network). My desktop's RDP connection doesn't work anymore though, getting stuck at a blank lock screen (power and accessibility options are there and the lock screen background is visible, but there are no login options). I've had this happen on an older desktop in the past, but I never found a solution other than reinstalling Windows. I've tested this from a Windows laptop, a MacBook, and my iPhone, all of which show the same behavior.

I saw this message on my phone's Remote Desktop app yesterday, but it might have been something else since my desktop was long overdue for a restart and was having other issues at time: https://imgur.com/a/VLjsz03

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on?